# Creating a Relationship Between Order Product (salesorderdetail) and Service Activity (serviceappointment)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

We are using Microsoft CRM 4.0 to run a consulting business. Its working pretty well but we want to simplify the way we are doing some things. What we want to do is create an Order (salesorder) with multiple Order Products (salesorderdetal). So good so far.

Next I want to be able associate each Order Product (salesorderdetail) with a Service Activity (serviceappointment), this representing that this billable line item in the order is actually going to be fulfilled as a consuting engagement.

The problem is, I can't seem to be able to create an association between the Order Product (salesorderdetail) and Service Activiy (serviceappointment). It simply doesn't appear in the drop downlist.

Can anyone think of a reason for this? I've seen some posts about relating field mapping between Quote Product, Order Product, Opportunity Product and Invoice Product, but that isn't quite what I am after.

Any suggestions gratefully received - even if it is an explaination of why its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple 1:N mapping from Case to Invoice. The Case records its ID and Title in custom fields in the Invoice. Unfortunately this does not allow for product creation as children of the Invoice, so that should be created as a custom code workflow.